# Import/Export a function from component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there a way to import a function from component in ReactJS Hooks?
Like, I have this component and function:

```
export default const Test(){
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

function TestFnc(){
setState(20)
}

return(
<p>{state}</p>
)
}
```

And I wonder how can I use that function `TestFnc` inside of other component? like this:

```
export default const Component(){

return(
<p onClick={()=> TestFnc()}>click me</p>
)
}
```

I know I could use class reactjs and export it to window DOM and use like this: `window.Test.TestFnc()` but with hooks is possible?

I tried custom Hooks but custom hooks didn't update the state
I've forgotten to mention, these components aren't related, they aren't parent and children.

Comment: You can use pass `TestFnc` to `Component` as props if `Component` is a child of `Test`. If not, you may need to [lift your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in your component tree. This could lead to prop-drilling of state and functions (ie: `TestFnc`), which you can resolve with creating a reducer and a context (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've exported my function to DOM like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.resetSearch = resetSearch;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass that function via props to the children of that component like this:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return <button onclick={() => props.fn()} />
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const myFn = () => {};

  return <ChildComponent fn={myFn} />
}
```

or use the React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), with Context the idea stays the same, but is a little more flexible as you can avoid [prop-drilling](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/avoid-prop-drilling-with-react-context-api/#:%7E:text=Prop%20drilling%20is%20a%20situation,where%20the%20data%20is%20needed.).

Comment: I've forgotten to mention, these components aren't related, they aren't parent and children.

Comment: Even so, this same pattern must be used, you need to have a top-level component that will provide that function to it's children. This gets a little bit more complicated, you'd need the component that defines the function to pass it up to one if its ancestors, and then that ancestor can pass it down to other components.